# Use a service with function reference in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, model-view-controller

I'm reading [some documentation](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) on Angular best practices and I've come across a section which states that [named functions for controllers are better than than anonymous](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y024).

```
/* recommended */

// dashboard.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

function DashboardController() { }
```

However, how can this work if I want to pass in a service? Using the anonymous syntax I used to it would just be

```
.controller('DashboardController', ['SomeService', function(SomeService){
  SomeService.someFn();
}]);
```

How can I do this by passing in a function so I can adhere to best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the array used for inline notation in a variable.

```
var DashboardController = function(SomeService) { };
var dashboardControllerArray = ['SomeService', DashboardController];
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DashboardController', dashboardControllerArray);
```

I personally don't feel this is necessary, though. You're already giving the name of the controller right before, which is just as descriptive as a variable name. You could do it if you intend to reuse a controller function, but if you're doing that, you may as well just create a reusable *AngularJS* controller.

I also wouldn't call the source you link "documentation". It's essentially a blog post that the author for some reason decided to host on GitHub, and it's explicit in that it's an opinion piece. It's not *wrong* (some of it's probably really helpful), but you don't need to take it as more than a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to specify dependencies in Angular. For one, you can use the same notation and just pass the named function instead of an anonymous function:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DashboardController', ['SomeService', DashboardController]);

function DashboardController (SomeService) { /* ... */ }
```

An alternative approach is to add an `$inject` property to your controller that contains all of the controller's dependencies. I like this approach because it keeps your module registration clean (you no longer need to specify dependencies when you register the controller):

```
angular
    .module('app')
    // SO FRESH AND SO CLEAN
    .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);

DashboardController.$inject = ['SomeService'];
function DashboardController (SomeService) { /* ... */ }
```